# Primitive float to int conversion is possible but same is not possible for reference type, why?

Tags: java, casting

This may be the simple answer but I want to know the detail.

```
// Narrowing Conversion
    float ff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int ii = (int)ff;

    System.out.println("float: " + ff + " int: " + ii);

    // Reference Conversion
    Integer integer;
    Float floatt = 100F;
    integer = (Integer) floatt;
```

In the above example the narrowing conversion works properly but the same with reference conversion is not working. Detail explanation is highly appreciable.

Comment: It is not possible because [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)  does not inherit from [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html). Autocasting on object does only work from sub- to superclasses, no exception. Explicit casting is not possible because `Integer` and `Float` do not have direct connection (the common superclass is not enough for typecasting).

Comment: Ok make sense. So for all the numeric type direct conversion is only possible to Number type.

Number number = floatt // because Number is a super type for Float class.

Comment: Just to be practical, you can use `floatt.intValue()` to *convert* a float to an int.

Comment: I saw you asked a lot of questions without [accepting one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If some answer help you, just click the green mark beside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `float`s to `int`s, but you cannot cast the wrapper objects to different types.  You must first unwrap the `Float` wrapper and then you can cast the primitive `float` to an `int`.

Java will auto box/unbox primitives and their wrapper types, java will also widen primitive types automatically.  But it won't do both.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see the bytecode for details. Use `javap -c` to see the byte codes.
The code

```
float ff = Integer.INT_MAX;
int ii = (int)ff;
```

compiles to

```
   0: ldc           #3                  // float 2.14748365E9f
   2: fstore_1
   3: fload_1
   4: f2i
   5: istore_2
```

If it's primitive type cast, as you can see from bytecode, [`f2i`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.f2i) is inserted by the compiler. (as line 4 shows).

On the other hand, if you use wrapper class, compiler doesn't insert any type conversion instruction.

That's why you cannot cast them.

Comment: Thanks for a providing a different perspective